How to change font size in plot R?
this is my code:
ggplot() +
geom_line(data = data1, aes(f, fsu), color = "green") +   #geom_point
geom_line(data = data2, aes(f, fsu), color = "black") +   #geom_point
geom_line(data = data.ref, aes(f, fsu), color = "red") +
scale_x_log10(limits = c(10^-4, 10), labels = scales::label_log()) +#labels = scales::label_log() pra ficar "10²"
scale_y_log10(labels = scales::label_log()) +
labs(x = "f(Hz)", y = "fS_u") 

and this is what i ploted:

i want to make the axis font size bigger but cex didn't work, any idea?
